# Unable to load template from a given location in Django

Tags: python, django

I am unable to load product_create.html using following url

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/create/
```

**Following is the error**
[image]

As you can see in the last line under heading **Template-loader postmortem**, it is searching for template in following location where my template is present (check project layout).

```
C:\trydjango\products\templates\products\product_create.html
```

**Following is my project layout**

[image: Following is my project layout].

Relevant part of settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR),"templates"],
        #'DIRS': [path.joinpath(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        #'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates' ],

        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from pages.views import home_view, contact_view, about_view
from products.views import product_detail_view,product_create_view
#its better fom the alternate version
#from pages import views and then using views.home_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_view ,name = 'home'),
    #the 1st argument to path gives the url
    path('admin', admin.site.urls),
    path('contact/', contact_view ,name = 'contact'),
    path('about/', about_view ,name = 'about'),
    path('product/', product_detail_view),
    path('create/', product_create_view),
]
```

products/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ProductForm
from .models import Product
# Create your views here.



def product_create_view(request):
    form = ProductForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

    context={
        'form':form
    }

    return render(request,"products/product_create.html",context)


def product_detail_view(request):
    obj=Product.objects.get(id=1)
    # context={
    #   'title':obj.title,
    #   'description':obj.description
    # }                 
    context={
        'object':obj
    }

    return render(request,"products/product_detail.html",context)
```

Comment: The indentation of your folder structure view seems to indicate that the 2 html files are actually outside of the innermost `products` folder and directly under `products/templates`.

Comment: can you verify whether or not the HTML files are in the folder? As schwobaseggl had said the files look like they are in the same directory as the templates > products folder but not actually inside the templates > products folder.